# Is AtherosSvc Safe?

Tags: windows-10, security, services

I have been looking through my services and noticed a service called "AtherosSvc" which has no description. It struck me as odd, as it is one of 10 services with no description, however all the others I know exactly what they are and what they do from their name. I did a quick google search and found that some sites called it a trojan, others said it was safe, and yet others said it was required for windows to function properly.

I am looking to know if AtherosSvc is safe and if it is, what does it do?

Details about the service:

- Path to executable: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\AdminService.exe`
- Startup type: Automatic
- Log on as: Local System account
- If this service fails: Take No Action
- Dependencies: None

Comment: Simple question, do you have an Atheros device, installed in your system?

Comment: I believe I have a Quallcomm QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter.

Comment: Atheros is owned by Qualcomm.  So have you tried to remove the software that uses the service in question?

Comment: The thing is, I have no idea what is using the service. That is why I came here

Comment: You have not supplied enough information for us to identify what installed the service.  However, it’s connected to your, Quallcomm device that much is clear

Comment: Well then tell me what to do or what information I should be providing to figure out what installed it, rather than being unhelpful and simply saying “Well, theres not enough info here”

Comment: If you uninstall the drivers for your device is the service also removed from your system?  The legitimate file is signed by  Atheros Quallcomm, is the file in question, signed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My research indicates that it is a Bluetooth driver for motherboards with built-in Bluetooth. However, most sites indicate that it should be found at %ProgramFiles%\Bluetooth Suite\adminservice.exe. The fact that yours is in C:\Windows\System32 *might* mean that it is not a legitimate version.

If you are not using any Bluetooth features, it won't hurt anything to disable the service.

Comment: I think it is interesting that I don't even have a Bluetooth Suite folder in my Program Files or Program Files (x86). I do use some Bluetooth features occasionally but not all that often. I'll try disabling it for a little bit and see if I notice any loss in functionality

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of Dells and on both PC's **AtherosSvc** is loaded from: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\AdminServioce.exe`

Looking at the properties of the exe...you can see the signiture.
[image]

For peace of mind...
Open Control Panel->Programs and Features
If you click `Qualcomm WLAN and Bluetooth Client Installation` you will be presented with a dialog box to repair the installation.

Answer (score 0):

My investigation provides a different answer.

1. My path is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\AdminService.exe... everything else about the setup above is the same ('drivers' an omission?),
2. Identified as the Microsoft Win 7 DDK driver (original name: setupapi.dll, plus digitally signed), and
3. i.e., the Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher. Conclusion: safe.